# Como listar el contenido de dos tablas en una vista con eloquent de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy listando el contenido de mas de dos tablas haciendo uso de query builder de este modo

```
$datos_anticipo=DB::table(liquidaciones)
                          ->join('liquidaciones_pago_anticipo','liquidaciones_pago_anticipo.cod_liquidacion','=','liquidaciones.cod_liquidacion')
                         ->join('proveedores','proveedores.cod_proveedor','=','liquidaciones.cod_proveedor')
                        ->select('liquidaciones_pago_anticipo.cod_liquidacion','proveedores.proveedor')
                       ->paginate(6);

return view ('anticipos.pago_anticipo',compact('datos_anticipo'));
```

mi pregunta es como puedo realizar lo mismo pero haciendo uso de eloquent de laravel

estos son mis modelos ya relacionados

modelo liquidaciones_pago_anticipo

```
class Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones_pago_anticipo';
    //protected $primaryKey = 'cod_anticipo_pago';
    protected $fillable=['cod_anticipo_pago',
                         'cod_liquidacion',
                         'fecha_pago',
                         'monto',
                         'cod_persona',
                         'cod_grupo_anticipo_pago',
                         'usuario'];

    public function liqui_a(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_liquidacion');
    }

    public function scopeLiquidacion ($query, $cod_liquidacion){
      if($cod_liquidacion)
      return $query->where('cod_liquidacion','LIKE',"%$cod_liquidacion%");
    }
```

modelo Proveedores

```
  class Proveedores extends Model
 {
        protected $table='proveedores';
        protected $primaryKey = 'cod_proveedor';
        protected $fillable=['cod_proveedor',
                             'proveedor',
                             'cod_cooperativa',
                             'cod_origen'];

        public function liqui_p(){
          return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_proveedor');
        }
    }
```

modelo liquidaciones este modelo actua como puente para aceder a los datos del modelo proveedores desde el modelo liquidaciones_pago_anticipo que es desde donde se parte al momento de hacer la consulta

```
 class Liquidaciones extends Model
    {
        protected $table='liquidaciones';
        protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';
        protected $fillable = ['cod_columna',
                               'cod_liquidacion',
                               'fecha_ingreso',
                               'fecha_liquidacion',
                               'cod_proveedor'];

        public function proveedor_p(){
          return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Proveedores','cod_proveedor');
        }

        public function pago_a(){                       
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo','cod_liquidacion','cod_liquidacion');
    }
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si amplías y explicas mejor que tipo de relación existe entre las 3 tablas

Comment: ya actualize mi pregunta añadiendo mas mis tres modelos relacionados

Answer (score 0):

Liquidaciones (aunque considero que por las convenciones de Laravel, el modelo debería estar en singular) es el modelo que contiene 2 relaciones.

- Una para la tabla proveedores
- Otra para la tabla de pago anticipado

Dado lo anterior podemos hacer uso de eager loading e indicarle dentro de un vector los siguientes valores

- los nombres de los métodos que declaramos para las relaciones
- Una función que por dentro procese el `select` de las columnas deseadas (esta parte la dejo pendiente y con mas tiempo posteriormente veré como constuirlo)

Propongo entonces

```
$data = Liquidaciones::with(['proveedor_p', 'pago_a'])->paginate(6);
```

Comment: realize los cambios indicados pero me salio el siguiente error                               QueryException in Connection.php line 666: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'proveedores.proveedor' in 'field list' (SQL: select `liquidaciones_pago_anticipo`.`cod_liquidacion`, `proveedores`.`proveedor` from `liquidaciones_pago_anticipo` where `liquidaciones_pago_anticipo`.`cod_liquidacion` in (85681, 86139, 4761, 5976, 7225, 240718))

Comment: @reivinbonshueder y que ocurrió?

Comment: @reivinbonshueder si esta consulta no te sirvió igual espera la que llegue a aportar por ejemplo Shaz seguro el te lo soluciona :)

Comment: grasias por la ayuda @Aprendiz

Comment: por cierto la ultima actualizacion que isiste en tu respuesta @Aprendiz si funciona es solo que la consulta tiene q partir desde el modelo Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo porq tengo q agregar un filtro con Scoope para q solo me liste los anticipos del usuario q se loguea, porq si parto desde el modelo liquidaciones me lista las liquidaciones q tiene el usuario logeado